# C++, гарантии исключений при перемещающей операции std::list<>::push_back(std::move())?

Tags: c++, list, исключения, move

Рассмотрим следующий код:

```
std::list<std::unique_ptr<Object>> objects;

std::unique_ptr<Object> object = std::make_unique<Object>();

// Do something with object.
// ...

try
{
    objects.push_back(std::move(object));
}
catch (...)
{
    // ...
}
```

Скажите, пожалуйста, что произойдет с `object` в случае генерации исключения? В официальной документации говорится о том, что `objects` останется в исходном состоянии, но про `object` не сказано ни слова. Объект останется в исходном состоянии, окажется пустым или сломанным?

Comment: push_back обеспечивает строгую безопасность исключения(ничего  не произойдет при генерации исключения), в том числе ничего не произойдет и с перемещаемым обьектом